# должны ли быть готовые значения для тестирования api c помощью постмана?

Tags: java, http, api

Дали документацию **api** в которой только **id** вызываемых параметров, но их значений нет. Чтобы отправить запрос по url адресу эти id, нужны ли мне уже существующие на сервере значения этих параметров? Использую *postman* с методом POST

Comment: скинь документацию post запроса

Comment: не совсем понятен вопрос, естественно для того, чтобы получить *корректный* результат нужны значения этих **id** в базе.

Comment: @БорисовМакс спасибо, я уже разобрался*